# Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected - Why?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm having trouble with the following code, where Xcode is flagging a memory problem. The warnings are below the code, on the return line. Does anybody know why, and what I can do about it?

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData];
}
```

> Mvariable.m:177:2: Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected
>   Mvariable.m:177:9: Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count
>   Mvariable.m:177:2: Object returned to caller with a +0 retain count
>   Mvariable.m:177:2: Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

methods that start with "copy", "create", "new", "alloc", or "retain", must return an object that has been retained, ie, the caller must release it.

`[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedData]` returns an autorelased object.

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: Note that using archiving to copy an object is definitely not typical.  It is also quite slow compared to the normal means of doing so.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realise the start of a method name alone could do this, how odd. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: in the old days it was just a convention and there wasn't ARC, or markers to `__strong` and `__weak` or the syntactic sweetness of `(__attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased)))`... so we had to keep track of things somehow...